# Select correct UITextField in a UITableView on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have  Static UItableView that has editble `UITextFields` in the rows.
I implemented an AutoComplete for one `UITextField`, that works fine. As the user types a new tableview is displayed that narrows down as the user types more characters. I like the feature so much, I wanted to implement it in 3 other textfields of the same table.

Think Make, Model, Body, Color of cars.

Now whenever I select any of the text fields I can start typing and the tableview will drill down, and the user can tap to their selection.

The only problem I am encountering is ***I don't know how to target the calling text field from the second tableview on didSelectRowAtIndexPath***.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
if (tableView == self.autocompleteTableView) {
    // HERE!! What do I compare against to see which textfield should get the autocomplete text?
            if (self.txt_model) {
                self.txt_model.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            if (self.txt_make) {

            }
            if (self.txt_color){

            }
            if (self.txt_body) {

            }

            self.hasChanged = YES;

        } else {
         /// other non important but working stuff
    }
```

**What do I compare against to see which textfield should get the autocomplete text?**

Before I implemented the other 3 drill downs, this what my didSelectRowAtIndexPath looked like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    if (tableView == self.autocompleteTableView) {
           self.txt_model.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
        ....
        }
    }
```

All the text fields are set up like this:

```
self.txt_model.inputAccessoryView = self.autocompleteTableView;
    self.txt_model.delegate = self;

    self.txt_make.inputAccessoryView = self.autocompleteTableView;
    self.txt_make.delegate = self;

    self.txt_body.inputAccessoryView = self.autocompleteTableView;
    self.txt_body.delegate = self;

    self.txt_color.inputAccessoryView = self.autocompleteTableView;
    self.txt_color.delegate = self;
```

Everything works as it should.

Comment: Declare a global textfield instance like : currentTxt; Implement the textfield delegates (didbeginediting) and assign the currentTxt to the textField value you are getting inside the delegate. In the didselect use the currentTxt as the target

Comment: That is it. Want to post it as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) methods.

You need to declare a global instance of `UITextField` like:

```
UITextField *currentTxt;
```

Implement the textfield delegate methods like:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    currentTxt = textField;
 }

 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    currentTxt = nil;
 }
```

And set the data like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Set the data using
   currentTxt.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I this you can use `[textField isFirstResponder]` for your problem, it can be helpful in deciding which textField is in focus.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    if (tableView == self.autocompleteTableView) {
           if([self.txt_model isFirstResponder]){
               self.txt_model.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           }
           else if([self.txt_make isFirstResponder]){
               self.txt_make.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           }
           else if([self.txt_color isFirstResponder]){
               self.txt_color.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           }
           else if([self.txt_body isFirstResponder]){
               self.txt_body.text = [self.arrAutoComplete objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           }
        } else {
        ....
        }
    }
```